# How to create single array from multi array?

Tags: php

Closed, this article not longer again to posted

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please consider explaining the details. Now it's not that informative.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = $questionArray[0];
```

The answer is not very detailed - but given the question, thats the best I can provide

Comment: I'll even upvote your answer, because it perfectly fits the style of the question :)